# I want it to close when it opens the exe file separately

Tags: c#, c++

I have two exe files coded in C# and C++. What I want to do is to download and run the exe coded with C++ from C#. When the C++ application is not brought from the C# application, I do not want it to be launched directly from the downloaded folder. How can I do this?

Comment: you can do this through md5/sha hash. Your c# stores the hash of the file you WILL download and compares it to the hash of the destiny file you HAVE downloaded. If the hashes match, there is no reason (according to your logic) to NOT execute the c++ exe file

Answer (score 2):

The C# app can pass a command-line parameter when it launches the C++ app.  If the C++ app does not see that parameter present, it can just terminate itself immediately without doing anything else.

```cs
Process.Start(@"c:\path to\cpp.exe", "-startedByCSharpApp");
```

```cpp
#include <string.h>

bool startedByCSharpApp(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-startedByCSharpApp") == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (startedByCSharpApp(argc, argv))
    {
        // normal operations here ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another option would be to have the C++ app call [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) and [`Process32First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32firstw)/[`Process32Next()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-process32nextw) to walk the list of running processes looking for itself and the C# app. See [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes). If both are not found, or if the C# app's process ID does not match its own process's `th32ParentProcessID`, it can terminate itself immediately.

```cpp
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool startedByCSharpApp()
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;

    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(pe32);

    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
        return false;
    }

    DWORD MyProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    DWORD MyParentProcessId = 0;
    std::vector<DWORD> CSharpAppPIDs;

    do
    {
        if (pe32.th32ProcessID == MyProcessId)
        {
            MyParentProcessId = pe32.th32ParentProcessID;
        }
        else if (_tcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, "csharp.exe") == 0)
        {
            CSharpAppPIDs.push_back(pe32.th32ProcessID);
        }
    }
    while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);

    if (MyParentProcessId != 0)
        return (std::find(CSharpAppPIDs.begin(), CSharpAppPIDs.end(), MyParentProcessId) != CSharpAppPIDs.end());

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    if (startedByCSharpApp())
    {
        // normal operations here ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no information about what you said. Do you have a chance to write a sample code?

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Have you never worked with command-line parameters before? Or called any Win32 API functions before?

Comment: yes i never called i dont know unfortunately i'm new :(

Comment: is there a sample video? Or I can search for what on googlede

Comment: The same rules I outlined earlier for the C++ app would apply to that C# app, you would just have to translate the C++ code above into C# equivalents.  StackOverflow is not a translation service.